# "Unique Name" in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I have implemented a NodeJS server which is capable of receiving streams from several users. But now, I have problems with the names of audio files.
A solution, that works for now is:

```
  var d = new Date();
  n = d.getTime();

    var fileWriter = new wav.FileWriter(n + '.wav', {
    channels: 1,
    sampleRate: 48000,
    bitDepth: 16
  });
```

So I am giving the milliseconds after 1970. This is not the prettier solution, and I want to give a "unique name" to each record. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What would you consider "prettier"? Have you considered [searching the npm repository](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=unique) for packages that might do what you want?

Comment: yes I already do that. Imagine that two clients starts streaming at precisely same time. What will happen? Never happen to me. But is possible

Comment: How about https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid then?

Comment: Not very elegant but after a few testes, work.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/unique-name <--this

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution:
[unique-name](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unique-name)

Usage:

```
var uniquename = require('unique-name');
var test = uniquename.gen();
console.log(test);
console.log(typeof test);//string
var test2 = uniquename.gen();
console.log(test2);
```